# is it valid to use a constructor inside defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to see if we can use a constructor inside defaultdict and I am not able to run the code and get a recursion error. Just wondering if it is possible:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self, char):
        self.children = defaultdict(TrieNode(char))
        self.is_word = False

 a = TrieNode('b')
```

Comment: Don't type code here. Copy-paste the code you run. If you do so, you won't make mistakes like missing a parameter to `__init__` call.

Comment: The defaultdict is incidental. Assuming your `__init__` method is supposed to have a `char` parameter, your problem is that the `__init__` for `TrieNode` is trying to create _another_ `TrieNode`, and that one will have to try and create another, which tries to create another, etc. That's an infinite recursion.

Comment: Apart from the infinite recursion: [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) expects a callable as the `default_factory` that returns the default object. You are passing a pre-constructed object.

Comment: Sorry I did not copy it correctly. I did run the code that is why I got a recursion error.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using a `defaultdict` in you constructor. The problem is that you need to pass it a function that *it* will call when you add new keys. You are currently calling the function when you make the dictionary. As a result you keep calling `TrieNode('b')` infinitely.

You need to call it with something like:

```
self.children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
```

Then when you reference an unknown key in `children` it will call `TrieNode()` for you. This means, however, that you don't want to take an additional argument in the constructor.

That's probably ok because you generally add words to a trie and will need to add many words through the same node. One option would be to do something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self.is_word = False
        self.val = ''

    def add(self, word):
        self.val= word[0]
        if (len(word) == 1):
            self.is_word = True
        else:
            self.children[word[0]].add(word[1:])

    def words(self):
        if self.is_word:
            yield self.val
        for letter, node in self.children.items():
            yield from (letter + child for child in node.words())
```

You can then add words to it and it will make TrieNodes in the default dictionary as it goes:

```
node = TrieNode()
node.add("dog")
node.add("catnip")
node.add("cats")
node.add("cat")
node.add("crunch")

node.children['c'].children

> defaultdict(__main__.TrieNode,
        {'a': <__main__.TrieNode at 0x179c70048>,
         'r': <__main__.TrieNode at 0x179c70eb8>})
```

You can see that your children has a `c` key which points to a TrieNode whose children is the defaultdict with `a` and `r` pointing to the next.

This allows you to easily pull out the words with a generator:

```
list(node.words())

> ['dog', 'cat', 'cats', 'catnip', 'crunch']
```